# QML module is not installed

Tags: qt, qml

I want to try import qml file.

And I already try QML_IMPORT_PATH, .qrc, qmldir.

But always got the error: QML module is not installed.

Please where am I missing?
I using Qt6.3, MacOS

[image]

here is .pro file

```
QT += quick

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH += $$PWD/Components

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1

INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += Components/qmldir
```

here is qmldir

```
Module Components

TestItem 1.0 TestItem.qml
```

here is qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Components/qmldir</file>
        <file>Components/TestItem.qml</file>
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

here is main.qml

```
import QtQuick
import TestItem 1.0
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

here is TestItem.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

}
```

I also push my test code on github
https://github.com/OtisLin123/QMLComponentTest

Comment: According to [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html), you should write "module Components" instead of "Module Components".

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. @m7913d
here I post the main.qml and the TestItem.qml.
I trying modify to module Components, I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While importing, you should specify the module name, and not the component name:

```
import Components 1.0 // instead of import TestItem 1.0
```

This will import all components included in the `qmldir`.